# when i run the app i am getting this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'preferences' in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

when i tried to run the app in django, i am getting this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'preferences'`, i have already installed `pip install django-dynamic-preferences`, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? here i have shown my whole error log

```
[2020-05-24 09:16:39 +0000] [13070] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-05-24 09:16:39 +0000] [13070] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (13070)
[2020-05-24 09:16:39 +0000] [13070] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-05-24 09:16:39 +0000] [13073] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13073
[2020-05-24 09:16:40 +0000] [13073] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/django-bhuriyo/bhuriyo/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'preferences'
[2020-05-24 09:16:40 +0000] [13073] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13073)
[2020-05-24 09:16:40 +0000] [13070] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-05-24 09:16:40 +0000] [13070] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: Are you using this app into Django project ?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanFareed yes i am using it

Comment: Are you already added into Installed apps ?

Comment: yes it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please share the code with us so that we can better understand your problem! I think this has to do with an import which was not properly done. Show us some code to help fix this.

Comment: thanks, i have resolved it by pip install django-userpreferences, sorry i was using wrong pip